# Application does not work in an other system

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a JavaFX Application in NetBeans using JDK8, which uses Derby.

The built project runs well, everything is fine at the first computer. Even if I run it from the "dist" library it is working properly.

But when I took to my mother's PC (same operation system - Windows 7) with 32 bit JRE, and I also installed the JDK the program runs well, but it cannot communicate with the database.

I can't create new records, can't read anything from the database like it wasn't.

Do I need to install the Apache Derby to my mother's computer? I wouldn't think so, since I am using a LOCAL Derby database. (the filesystem is the same, the database folder can be found at the dist folder, so it SHOULD work.)

There is no error message, just does not do what it should. (for example does not list the records from the database at the main screen)

What do I wrong?

Comment: Is it an embedded database?

Comment: Good question! This should be the problem! The path of the database is referenced to my C://document and settings/netbeansproject/Application/    When I run it the program finda ir but my mother's computer does not find this location. How can I make it embedded?

Comment: You can find all the information in [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html)

Comment: using static file paths does not work between different computers, of course. Thats absolutely logical and if you actually thought that these paths could work you ..... should re-start from the beginning, you still have much to learn. Sorry. A quick solution could be : change your absolute path to a relative one.

Comment: I have just forgotten that I did not set absolute path. But still: of coarse I have to learn ;) As everyone does. But that's the reason of this page. To learn and ask other's what did I wrong. After writing 6.000 lines of codes I still have obvious settings I did not set correctly, that's why I need others who see what I can't

Comment: whats an "obvious setting"?

Comment: "Obvious setting" means something which is quite basic. What does not require a great knowledge.
Obvious settings for me for example to set the database path correctly. I did not realize I set it not relatively, so the solution was obvious I just wasn't able to find the problem 'cause i thought the problem is somewhere else. Anyway, thank you ItachiUchica for the help!